# "chevron" style nav bar in CSS & browser scaling problems

Tags: html, css

I've been experimenting with making a HTML/CSS navigation bar with chevron-shaped list items. I've made my code available here: https://github.com/twslankard/css-chevron-bar/blob/master/index.html

Since my question is fairly specific, I'm offering up the code as public domain in the off chance that one of you CSS wizards will help me. :)

Now for my question. I've been trying to design the bar so that it scales properly, e.g. when someone modifies the font-size property of `ul.chevronbar li` or when the user hits `Control+` or `Control-` in the browser.

I tried using two different CSS resets, both Eric Meyers Reset CSS 2.0 and YUI 3. However, in Firefox the scaling/zooming "mostly" works, and in Chrome it does not work (especially when zooming in). If possible, I'd like some advice on how to get this to work better in Chrome.

Here's an image illustrating the issue. Your help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

EDIT: this is what I ended up with eventually. Pardon the messy CSS. I'll get around to cleaning it up later.

https://github.com/twslankard/css-chevron-bar-2

EDIT 2: Another person generously provided their solution to this problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/pXBTK/3/

Comment: Tom, it may be just Friday, but I don't see where you are creating the shapes? I assume you are using background images or are you doing it in  `content: ' ';`?

Comment: Excellent question, Ryan. I'm actually using the "cssarrow" trick, which uses the border property to create those triangle-like shapes. For example, http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: And yes, the content: ' ' is what's creating the extra shapes in conjunction with the borders.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/triangle-breadcrumbs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effectively, the trick is how to make the height of the pointy parts match the height of the menu item it follows, thus avoiding the jagged look.

I am guessing that something like this causes the problem:

- Calculated menu item height is 5 physical screen pixels
- Each of the top and bottom borders that produce the arrow must be 50% of 5
- Since you cannot display a half pixel, both round off, say to 3 pixels
- Add together and the arrow becomes 6 pixels tall but menu item is only 5

It seems clear then that the fix is to simply hide the overflow as stated. The only change really necessary to the original is:

```
ul.chevronbar {
  ...
  overflow: hidden; /* Add this line */
}
```

It would also need resizing to get closer to the original look, but works without that. Fixed height is not actually necessary.

This simplified example illustrates the arrow concept with highlighting for parts of the arrow:

```
<head><style type="text/css">
ul {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: xx-large;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
li:after {
  content: '';
  border: 0.85em solid blue;
  border-left-color: red;
  border-right-color: red;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.2em;
}
</style></head>
<body><ul>
  <li>Lorem Ipsum</li> <li>Foobar</li>
</ul></body>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. That description allowed me to solve the problem. The only change I had to make to get good behavior in both browsers was to make the :after element have a border size in pixels rather than em. (Plus, I had to adjust the vertical placement, but that was simple as well.)

Answer (score 3):

There's two main issues here.

1) The first is that you're applying positioning to items that don't really make sense? 
Example: When you set position: absolute; vertical-align: top; will do nothing because it only applies to inline elements.

The second is that you haven't really thought about the problem in much detail, and it just looks like you're sticking coding wherever you can.

So take a step back and think about what each element does, and lay out steps to achieve it. We start out with a black box and end up with a box with chevrons.

1) I create a fixed height container, and then set it to overflow:hidden; that way, anything over a certain height will not be shown.

2) I set the position of the elements much differently than you did. My list elements are floated left.

3) Then put margins and padding to space the list elements.

4) Last, I put in the chevrons and style those.

Here is an example of what I did...

```
ul.chevronbar {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; height:50px; width:auto; overflow:hidden;}
ul.chevronbar li {margin: 0; padding: 0; height:50px; width:auto; border:1px solid #000; position:relative; float:left; background:#333; font-size: 1.5em; margin-right: 1em; padding: 0 0.7em; }
ul.chevronbar li a {text-decoration: none; color: #fff; line-height:50px; display:block;}
ul.chevronbar li:before, ul.chevronbar li:after {content: ' '; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; top:-2px; border: 1.2em solid transparent; border-left-width: 0.45em; border-right-width: 0.45em;}
ul.chevronbar li:before {border-top-color: #333; border-bottom-color: #333; border-right-color: #333; right: 100%;}
ul.chevronbar li:after {border-left-color: #333; left: 100%; margin-left: -0.01em;}
li.first {padding-left: 0.5em;}
li.first:before {border: none !important ;}
li.last:after {border: none !important;}
```

Comment: Actually, I have thought about the problem quite a bit; I'm just not very experienced with CSS.

Comment: About the vertical positioning: does it make no difference that the li elements have "display: inline"?

Comment: BTW... was going to upvote you but your tone is pretty snide. Are you like this with co-workers?